# How do I switch multiple materials in the geometry node editor with the new index switch node?

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes

[image]

I am currently trying to build a geometry node setup with the new Index Switch Node that can switch the assigned material of an object around, that I can just write 1, 2 or 3 into the Index Switch Index field and the cube becomes red, green or blue. This would also be very useful for a face and mouth material switch animation, like animating Lego figures.

I know that this already works with more complex Material Nodes setups, but it would also be cool to have a Geometry Nodes solution.

Something in my Geometry Nodes setup is wrong, when I write in different values in the Index Switch Index field the cube stays red.

Does anyone know how to get it working?

Comment: The _Join Geometry_ node is useless - it joins geometry  But in the upper socket you just plug a _Set Material_ node with nothing in the _Geometry_ input. So you join empty geometry with the cube to which you do not assign a new material. Plug the cube in the _Set Material_ node and delete the _Join Geometry_.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Thank you for the information, but... In what way do you want me to plug the cube? Is there a node for that that takes the object? What is that node called if yes? I have very little experience with geometry nodes

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you basically have no real idea how _Geometry Nodes_ work? Have you done any tutorials on _Geometry Nodes_? You said in the question you know this would work with more complex setups but you wanted to try the new _Index Switch_ node... this made me think you know the GN basics. When you add _Geometry Nodes_ to an object - in this case your cube - the original mesh (the cube) is fed into the nodetree through the _Group Input_ node's _Geometry_ output. The reason you still see the cube is because it is plugged into the _Group Output_ node's _Geometry_ input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the *Set Material* node you have no geometry plugged in to which you want to assign the material to, that's why you see nothing changing.

Assuming you want to change the material of the base object (the geometry you get from the *Group Input* node), plug it into the *Geometry* input of the *Set Material* node.

For the *Index Switch* node: you can plug *Material* nodes in there, but you could also simply choose them in the fields themselves. By default the switch node has only two inputs, but you can add more in the *Node Properties* with the *Add Item* button.

[image: index switch]

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it.

Comment: You're welcome, no need to thank me but please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)